# Juno: Youtube videos pause when mouse stops moving (Chromium)

Tags: release-juno

Watching youtube videos I noticed that whenever my cursor is on top of the video itself it the video will stop (visual only) when the cursor pauses. This was after updating to Juno

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and can be followed [here](https://github.com/elementary/os/issues/121).

Disabling hardware acceleration in chrome settings seems to solve the issue.

To do so go to `//settings/?search=hardware%20acceleration` and disable 'Use hardware acceleration when available'.